# Vue3 web component set attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, web-component

I created stand alone web component, with Vite and Vue3, to replace old jQuery libraries.

When rendered in html, it looks something like:

```
<custom-datepicker id="deliveryTime">
  #shadow-root
  <div>...actual component...</div>
</custom-datepicker>
```

When user select date it would be perfect if I can set attribute `value` to this element, like:

```
<custom-datepicker value="selected value HERE" ...
```

so the form can then use this value from the element by it's id.

Problem is that the only way I manage to achieve this is by emitting event (`selected`) from my web component and listening to that event, so the form can use value, like:

```
const datepicker = document.querySelector('#deliveryTime');
const dateSelected = (e) => {
  datepicker.value = e.detail.val;
}
window.addEventListener('selected', dateSelected);
```

If I set value attribute within web component, rest of the app (Apache Velocity template) can't access it because it is in the shadow-root:

```
<custom-datepicker id="deliveryTime">
  #shadow-root
  <div value="selected value is sadly HERE">...actual component...</div>
</custom-datepicker>
```

Is it even possible to achieve this from inside the web component (so I can omit listener)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, maybe not the cleanest one but it works :)

In my web-component, in mounted hook component is selected:

```
const dp = ref(null)
onMounted(() => {
  dp.value = document.querySelector("#deliveryTime");
})
```

After date is selected, instead of emitting just set attribute:

```
dp.value.setAttribute('value', value)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you access the HTMLElement linked to your shadowhost and then use the "setAttribute" function on it ? Assuming you have access to the shadowRoot inside your  component using 'this', I think something like that will do the trick (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/host) :

```
const shadowHost = this.shadowRoot.host; // The HTMLElement linked to <custom-datepicker />
shadowHost.setAttribute("value", someValueOfYourChoice);
```